# Web-facing Server Backup

Tags: backup

I am currently running a web-facing server with the root filesystem on an external USB disk with another USB disk attached and destined for backup of the server.

What I really need to do, however, is to have a full backup system running as a scheduled cron task, with incremental backups and/or compression, as well as an easy to run restore procedure or script.

My setup is as follows:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL="PI BOOT" UUID="6654-8624" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="rootfs" UUID="6d300a32-1cd7-46ab-be6f-c30c2bc51519" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="The Pad Backup" UUID="ec33414c-b925-d101-a012-404cb925d101" TYPE="ext4"

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       917G  3.9G  867G   1% /
devtmpfs        459M     0  459M   0% /dev
tmpfs            93M  1.4M   92M   2% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           186M     0  186M   0% /run/shm
/dev/mmcblk0p1  968M   40M  929M   5% /boot
none            463M     0  463M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

Please note: **This is not about backing up an SD card**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Jack

Comment: Hi, maybe this article can be intereted for you : http://sysmatt.blogspot.cl/2014/08/backup-restore-customize-and-clone-your.html :)

Comment: Regarding your edit ("Please note this is not about backing up an SD card"), it does very clearly seem to be about backing up *the root filesystem*, which is the topic of the duplicate question.  It doesn't matter what the medium is.  There is not, e.g., a special backup system, written only for the raspberry pi, and more specifically only for filesystems on attached storage attached to a raspberry pi.  That would be absurd and contradicts some basic premises of good software engineering.

Comment: ...Have an actual look at what's available and has been recommended, and if you can formulate a question about why none of these existing solutions are appropriate to your situation, then great -- but I am sure you cannot, unless there is some special information you have neglected to include here originally.

Comment: Hi Goldilocks, I must apologise if I have caused offence. When I saw the "Duplicate" notice, I got brassed off because I assumed the post I unwitting duplicated was about cloning one's SD card, something I have seen many posts about lately. I have since followed the link at the top of this page and found rsnapshot to be very useful and will be voting up the person who suggested it.